# Copy data from each column based in if condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in a sheet which looks like

```
A      B      C       D
       1001   1002    1003
Phone  1      1       1
TV     1              1
Remote                1
AC     1      1       1
```

I want a macro to which gives Data in another sheet something like

```
Phone  1001;1002;1003
TV     1001;1003
Remote 1003
AC     1001;1002;1003
```

in 2 columns

This is Sample data, the columns and rows vary every time to large numbers say up to 1000.
So I need a macro to get the data from first row, only if corresponding cell has "1" in it.

Comment: Having "I want a ..." in your question is a rather good indicator that it might [not be on-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810).

Answer (score 0):

This might help ..

```
Sub Init()
Dim x, y As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim xt As Worksheet

Set xt = Sheets("Sheet2")'----------> you may change this

For y = 2 To 6 '--------------------tv,remote,etc
  s = ""
  For x = 2 To 4 '------------------1001,1002,1003
    If Cells(y, x) = 1 Then
      If Len(s) > 0 Then s = s & "; "
      s = s & Cells(1, x)
    End If
  Next
  xt.Cells(y, 1) = Cells(y, 1)
  xt.Cells(y, 2) = s
Next
End Sub
```